# Outline text duplicate characters

Tags: fonts, vector, adobe-acrobat, character, outline

I have a large document in which I am converting texts to outlines using Adobe Acrobat Pro. But when I do so, the file size increases significantly. It is because it turns every character into a unique object. But if it converted every same character e.g., all e's of the same font to a symbol, then the file size would have been much smaller. Is there any program that is capable of doing so?

Comment: Yes -- any remotely capable PDF creator does this. The collection of outlines is called a "font".

Comment: But the fonts can be copied, while the outlines cannot. Can the fonts be rendered unrecognisable?

Comment: Why do you want to turn your text to outlines?? I can't see any good reason for that; even the dumbest print shops are beginning to handle PDF properly…

Comment: I want to render the fonts unrecognisable by any software that reads pdf

Comment: **Why** do you need fonts unrecognizable?? I can't think of any reason for that. - And once you outline type each and every path becomes solitary artwork, it's no longer a a collection of references to a built in library (font). So, naturally 1000 type characters that contain a common 26 characters, will be smaller in terms of KB than 1000 separate vector objects.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably also available via Acrobat Pro: in InDesign's export to PDF panel you have options to password-protect files against printing, editing ***and/or*** copying of text. Not sure if this works for you, but it is something to consider instead of having huge files with outlined text.

[image]